# 3D Plot not showing up

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have plotted this :

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection= '3d')
zline = np.linspace(0, 16, 10000)
xline = np.sin(zline)
yline = np.cos(zline)
ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, 'red')
```

[image]

However when i plot the following code nothing shows up:

```
zdata = np.random.random(500)
xaxis = np.sin(zdata)
yaxis = np.cos(zdata)
ax.scatter3D(xaxis, yaxis, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='Greens')
```

Three is just `<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Path3DCollection at 0x20e10b546c8>` but the graph is not plotted? Why is that?

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling that because you are doing inline plotting you need to create a new figure, just add the first two lines of the first bit of code to the second.

Comment: You are right. That solved it!

Comment: Let me put it as an answer then, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are plotting inline, you will need to create a new figure (as in the first section):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection= '3d')
zdata = np.random.random(500)
xaxis = np.sin(zdata)
yaxis = np.cos(zdata)
ax.scatter3D(xaxis, yaxis, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='Greens')
```

When inline a plot wont update. Hope this helps!